# symfony form collection data transformer - A cycle was detected

Tags: forms, symfony

I've created Symfony collection forms with data transformer but during submit form this error occures: "A cycle was detected. Listeners to the PRE_SET_DATA event must not call getData() if the form data has not already been set. You should call getData() on the FormEvent object instead."

```
class BankTransferPackageType extends AbstractType
{
    /** {@inheritdoc} */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('transfers', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => BankTransferType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'prototype' => false,
        ]);

        $builder->add('save', SubmitType::class);
    }

    /** {@inheritdoc} */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'data_class' => BankTransferPackage::class
            ]
        );
    }

    /** {@inheritdoc} */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return '';
    }
}

class BankTransferType extends AbstractType
{
    /** {@inheritdoc} */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('order', OrderIdHiddenType::class);
    }

    /** {@inheritdoc} */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'data_class' => BankTransfer::class
            ]
        );
    }

    /** {@inheritdoc} */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return '';
    }
}

class OrderIdHiddenType extends AbstractType
{
    /** @var OrderToIdTransformer */
    protected $orderToIdTransformer;

    /**
     * OrderIdHiddenType constructor.
     *
     * @param OrderToIdTransformer $orderToIdTransformer
     */
    public function __construct(OrderToIdTransformer $orderToIdTransformer)
    {
        $this->orderToIdTransformer = $orderToIdTransformer;
    }

    /** {@inheritdoc} */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addModelTransformer($this->orderToIdTransformer);
    }

    /** {@inheritdoc} */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return HiddenType::class;
    }
}
```

When I change:

```
$builder->add('order', OrderIdHiddenType::class);
```

to:

```
$builder->add('test', TextType::class);
```

form submission works well

and I need to set: 'prototype' => false, because with true my OrderToIdTransformer throw exception because he received null data.

What is wrong and how to fix it? thanks for you help!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide some code which shows your problem or how far you got by now on your own. See [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Answer (score -1):

I've fix it (prototype true and return null if null in transformer), but does anyone know how to change OrderIdHiddenType to OrderIdCheckboxType with value attribute equal to order id from database?